# ¿Cómo agrupar dataframe datetime por mes para hacer recuentos mensuales de ocurrencia?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, date, plotly

Tengo un marco de datos de las razones por las que se rechazó un pago, con la fecha, que tiene el siguiente aspecto:

```
>>>df[['Message retour auto.', 'Date du paiement']]

    Message retour auto.                        Date du paiement
0   Transaction non permise à ce porteur        28/07/2021 03:10:00
1   NaN                                         28/07/2021 03:10:00
2   Ne pas honorer                              28/07/2021 03:10:00
3   NaN                                         28/07/2021 03:10:00
4   Provision insuffisante ou crédit dépassé    28/07/2021 03:10:00
... ... ...
3601    Ne pas honorer                          01/01/2021 03:10:00
3602    Ne pas honorer                          01/01/2021 03:10:00
3603    Ne pas honorer                          01/01/2021 03:10:00
3604    Transaction non permise à ce porteur    01/01/2021 03:10:00
3605    Provision insuffisante ou crédit dépassé    01/01/2021 03:10:00
```

Me gustaría mostrar la suma de cada una de las razones por mes, así que hice:

```
message_names = df['Message retour auto.'].unique()
df = df.groupby(["Date du paiement","Message retour auto."]).size()

import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

temp = df.groupby(["Date du paiement","Message retour auto."]).size()

temp1 = temp.rename('size').reset_index()


message_d = {}

for message in message_names:
  message_d[message] = temp1[temp1["Message retour auto."]==message]

data = []

for message in message_d.keys():
      data.append(go.Bar(name=str(message), 
                         x=message_d[message]['Date du paiement'], 
                         y=message_d[message]['size']))


fig = go.Figure(data=data)

fig.update_layout(barmode='stack')
```

Pero me devuelve:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No es muy agradable...

Pueden ver el colab notebook [aqui](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1_U96W9KVSL77CtPlWn61dF2GbyMdf44G?usp=sharing).

## Con la respuesta de Christian

Tengo un problema con `df.resample("M")["Message retour auto"]` porque me parece que crea fechas que no existen. En efecto las ultimas fechas de mi dataframe estan:

```
>>>df_original['Date du paiement'].tail()
Date du paiement
2020-04-05 10:33:00   2020-04-05 10:33:00
2020-04-05 07:19:00   2020-04-05 07:19:00
2020-04-05 03:10:00   2020-04-05 03:10:00
2020-04-05 03:10:00   2020-04-05 03:10:00
2020-04-05 03:10:00   2020-04-05 03:10:00
```

Pero cuando hizo:

```
df_original['Date du paiement'] = pd.to_datetime(df_original['Date du paiement'])
df_original.index = df_original['Date du paiement']
df = df_original.resample("M")["Message retour auto."].agg(lambda x: Counter(list(x)))
df = df.to_frame()
df
```

Me devuelve fechas en 01/2020:

```
    Message retour auto.
Date du paiement    
2020-01-31  {'Provision insuffisante ou crédit dépassé': 2...
2020-02-29  {'Provision insuffisante ou crédit dépassé': 8...
2020-03-31  {'Provision insuffisante ou crédit dépassé': 7...
2020-04-30  {'Transaction non permise à ce porteur': 2, 'N...
2020-05-31  {'Ne pas honorer': 36, 'Transaction non permis...
2020-06-30  {'Ne pas honorer': 53, 'Provision insuffisante...
2020-07-31  {'Provision insuffisante ou crédit dépassé': 3...
2020-08-31  {'Ne pas honorer': 61, 'Transaction non permis...
2020-09-30  {'Provision insuffisante ou crédit dépassé': 2...
2020-10-31  {'Transaction non permise à ce porteur': 20, '...
2020-11-30  {'Ne pas honorer': 58, 'Transaction non permis...
2020-12-31  {'Ne pas honorer': 45, 'Provision insuffisante...
2021-01-31  {'Transaction non permise à ce porteur': 49, '...
2021-02-28  {'Ne pas honorer': 46, 'Provision insuffisante...
2021-03-31  {'Ne pas honorer': 47, 'Transaction non permis...
2021-04-30  {'Ne pas honorer': 43, 'Suspicion de fraude': ...
2021-05-31  {'Transaction non permise à ce porteur': 35, '...
2021-06-30  {'Ne pas honorer': 40, 'Conserver la carte': 5...
2021-07-31  {'Ne pas honorer': 42, 'Provision insuffisante...
2021-08-31  {'Transaction non permise à ce porteur': 13, '...
2021-09-30  {'Ne pas honorer': 5, 'Provision insuffisante ...
2021-10-31  {'Ne pas honorer': 9, 'Transaction invalide': ...
2021-11-30  {'Ne pas honorer': 15, 'Transaction non permis...
2021-12-31  {'Ne pas honorer': 8, 'Date de validité de la ..
```

Comment: cual es el problema en si? agrupar los datos por mes? o hacer la gráfica más bonita?

Comment: Agrupar los datos por mes @Christian Me ocuparé de la estética más tarde

Answer (score 0):

Para poder agrupar por lapsos de tiempo, pandas nos trae un método llamado `resample()`, el cual puede agrupar por:

- Día natural (`D`)
- Día hábil (`B`)
- Semanal (`W`)
- Mensual (`M`)
- Bimensual (`SM`)
- Trimestral (`Q`)

Por lo que vamos a usar como parámetro la letra `M` para agrupar por mes, pero antes necesitamos establecer los índices como fechas.

```py
#replicando tu DataFrame
cols = ["Message retour auto","Date du paiement"]
data = [["Transaction non permise à ce porteur","28/07/2021 03:10:00"],
["NaN","28/07/2021 03:10:00"],
["Ne pas honorer","28/07/2021 03:10:00"],
["NaN","28/07/2021 03:10:00"],
["Provision insuffisante ou crédit dépassé","28/07/2021 03:10:00"],
["Ne pas honorer","01/01/2021 03:10:00"],
["Ne pas honorer","01/01/2021 03:10:00"],
["Ne pas honorer","01/01/2021 03:10:00"],
["Transaction non permise à ce porteur","01/01/2021 03:10:00"],
["Provision insuffisante ou crédit dépassé","01/01/2021 03:10:00"]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)

#cambiamos los índices a fechas
df['Date du paiement'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date du paiement'])
df.index = df['Date du paiement']
```

Con todo esto hecho ahora ya podemos usar el método `resample()`, y podemos acceder a tributos como `count`, `sum`, `mean`

```py
df.resample("M")["Message retour auto"].unique()
```

Esto agrupará las fechas por mes y escogerá la columna `Message retour auto` y obtendrá los valores únicos, esto lo almacenará en una lista donde ya puedes tratarlos como quieras, pero recordemos que solo aparecerán los valores una vez. Si quieres obtener toda la lista de los valores puedes optar por el método `agg()` y pasarle una lmabda

```py
df.resample("M")["Message retour auto"].agg(lambda x: list(x))
```

Esto creará una lista con todos los valores.

Comment: Muchas gracias, mero con `df.resample("M").count()` pierdo las informaciones en la columna `Message retour auto.`, como puedo conservarlos para hacer un count sobre los mensajes de `"Message retour auto"` ?

Comment: hacer esto `df.resample("M")["Message retour auto"].count()`??

Comment: Por desgracia solo me devuelve cuantos elementos hay cada mez en la columna pero necesito cuantos elementos que pertenecen a los differentes mensajes

Comment: sabias que si haces `df.resample("M").sum()` se te concatenará todos los valores de tu DF? puedes jugar con eso

Comment: @RevolucionforMonica he editado la respuesta, creo que ahora si se adapta a lo que quieres.

Comment: Tengo un problema con `df_original.resample("M")` me parece que crea fechas que no existen en df. He puesto al dia mi pregunta para mostrarte